# Re-Render EJS template in express node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, discord.js, ejs

So I am using discord.js along with express and I want my webpage to update whenever the `client.on("message")` is fired. As far as I know and from research the only way possible to render a ejs template was on a get request, so how should I go about this.

this is my `index.js`

```js
const express = require("express")
const https = require('https')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const config = require('./config.json')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
app.use(express.static("public"))

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", function(message) { 
    console.log(message.author.username + " : "+ message.content)    
    // I want a res.render("index", {data : message.author.username + " : "+ message.content })       //equivalent here           
}); 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render("index", {data : "EMPTY"}) 
})


app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("Running")
})

client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Comment: This cannot be done as both of these things happen in events (e.g. a discord message and a GET request) so you can't force updates to a user unless you're using sessions, or websockets.

Comment: Could You tell a solution to this, because this is very neccessary for what I am trying to acheive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using socket.io First install socket.io `npm i socket.io`
Then update your application to use the socket.io engine.

```js
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const config = require('./config.json')
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
```

Update "index" file. Make sure the text your trying to update has `id="count"`.

```js
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('count', function(data){
        $('#count').html(data.count);
      });
    </script>
```

Now finally update command.

```js
client.on("message", function(message) { 
    console.log(message.author.username + " : "+ message.content)
    data = message.author.username + " : "+ message.content
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(sockets){
    sockets.emit('count',{count:data});
})      
});
```